# Problem with building OpenVPN Core c++ project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake

I have an OpenVPN core project which is written in C++, and I want to build it in Visual Studio 2019. It gives me an error about `CMake, but I installed CMake and tried it again but it was not solved.

The project is on Github in this [link](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3)

and this error in Visual Studio:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression
>   State Suppression State Error     CMake Error at C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Microsoft Visual
>   Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137
>   (message):   Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL
>   root folder in the   system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing:
>   OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY   OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)     C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Microsoft Visual
>   Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake 137

Comment: Just follow the instructions https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3/blob/master/README.rst#building-the-openvpn-3-client-on-windows

Comment: i did it but not works

Comment: as the error states(** ...try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR ...**), VisualStudio is not able to find the OpenSSl. Please, make sure that the environment variable mentioned in the error is set.